# Bind to DataGridTemplateColumn containing ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I need to bind one DataColumn to object representing SeletectedItem of ComboBox which is inside DataGridTemplateColumn. I tried almost everything, however I was able only to bind to Header of antother column.

the XAML looks like this:

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="MealPartsColumn" Header="Składniki">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox x:Name="MealPartsComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MealParts}" SelectedIndex="0" SelectedValuePath="{Binding FoodQuantity}">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FoodProduct.ProductName}" Width="100"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ElementName=MealPartsComboBox, Path=SeletectedItem.FoodQuantity}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Ilość w gramach" Width="100"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

My model describing this is:

```
public class Meal
{
    public List<MealPart> MealParts { get;set; }
}

public class MealParts
{
    public float FoodQuantity {get;set;}
    public FoodProduct FoodProduct {get;set;}
}

public class FoodProduct 
{
    public string ProductName {get;set;}
}
```

Relevant backend code:

```
Meals = new ObservableCollection<Meal>(mealsForDay);
HistoryDataGrid.ItemsSource = Meals;
```

**ProductName in ComboBox is populating properly, however, I cannot bind it to TextColumn.**

**This is the code I made that is finally working. I needed to set explicitly UpdateSourceTrigger for that solution to work.**

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="MealPartsColumn" Header="Składniki">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox x:Name="MealPartsComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="FoodProduct.ProductName" ItemsSource="{Binding MealParts}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMealPart, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ilość w gramach" Binding="{Binding SelectedMealPart.FoodQuantity, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: I think some of your problem could be coming from the fact that you're binding by element name when that element exists on each row in the grid. I'll have time in the morning to dig further if you don't have an answer by then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do this by binding via a property on your `Meal`:

```
public class Meal : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<MealPart> MealParts { get;set; }
    public MealPart SelectedMealPart {
        get { return _selected;  }
        set { _selected = value;
             // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged and fire the event here
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to get the bindings to update correctly.

Then:

```
<ComboBox ... SelectedItem={Binding SelectedMealPart}" ...>
```

And:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SelectedMealPart.FoodQuantity}" ...>
```